# Panic reports/ Mac keeps on restarting

Tags: macos, crash, kernel-panic, driver

Does anyone know what this means?

```
Anonymous UUID:       8195C90F-BAA5-F742-8694-AE59F9D349D3

Wed Apr 15 22:20:40 2015

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 4 caller 0xffffff7fa8c4ff63): "GPU Panic: [<None>] 3 0 a0 d9 9 8 0 3 : NVRM[0/1:0:0]: Read Error 0x00000100: CFG 0xffffffff 0xffffffff 0xffffffff, BAR0 0x104000000 0xffffff8137e10000 0x0e7150a2, D0, P3/4\n"@/SourceCache/AppleGraphicsControl/AppleGraphicsControl-3.7.21/src/AppleMuxControl/kext/GPUPanic.cpp:127
Backtrace (CPU 4), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff8133f6ad30 : 0xffffff8025f3a811 
0xffffff8133f6adb0 : 0xffffff7fa8c4ff63 
0xffffff8133f6ae90 : 0xffffff7fa6c6cd28 
0xffffff8133f6af50 : 0xffffff7fa6d371b6 
0xffffff8133f6af90 : 0xffffff7fa6d37226 
0xffffff8133f6b000 : 0xffffff7fa6f6ed7e 
0xffffff8133f6b090 : 0xffffff7fa6f8650b 
0xffffff8133f6b0d0 : 0xffffff7fa6dafa13 
0xffffff8133f6b100 : 0xffffff7fa6daf99d 
0xffffff8133f6b130 : 0xffffff7fa6ebdc9f 
0xffffff8133f6b160 : 0xffffff7fa6ebf971 
0xffffff8133f6b200 : 0xffffff7fa6ebff38 
0xffffff8133f6b280 : 0xffffff7fa6c81bbf 
0xffffff8133f6b2d0 : 0xffffff7fa6ec4157 
0xffffff8133f6b430 : 0xffffff7fa6ec45fa 
0xffffff8133f6b4b0 : 0xffffff7fa6d6ebee 
0xffffff8133f6b680 : 0xffffff7fa6d6d78f 
0xffffff8133f6b6c0 : 0xffffff7fa6d7d8f8 
0xffffff8133f6b720 : 0xffffff7fa6d77d63 
0xffffff8133f6b740 : 0xffffff7fa6d33f76 
0xffffff8133f6b780 : 0xffffff7fa6d33060 
0xffffff8133f6b7e0 : 0xffffff7fa6c70164 
0xffffff8133f6b800 : 0xffffff7fa6c70b5b 
0xffffff8133f6ba20 : 0xffffff7fa6c70e48 
0xffffff8133f6bac0 : 0xffffff7fa6c1e330 
0xffffff8133f6bb40 : 0xffffff7fa6c1db9e 
0xffffff8133f6bba0 : 0xffffff7fa6c1f4c6 
0xffffff8133f6bbe0 : 0xffffff7fa6bd18d0 
0xffffff8133f6bc70 : 0xffffff7fa6bc98ac 
0xffffff8133f6bcb0 : 0xffffff7fa6c20164 
0xffffff8133f6bd00 : 0xffffff80264b85b1 
0xffffff8133f6bd50 : 0xffffff80264ff0b5 
0xffffff8133f6bdc0 : 0xffffff8025fea95e 
0xffffff8133f6be10 : 0xffffff8025f3e91c 
0xffffff8133f6be40 : 0xffffff8025f235a3 
0xffffff8133f6be90 : 0xffffff8025f33e8d 
0xffffff8133f6bf10 : 0xffffff802600a142 
0xffffff8133f6bfb0 : 0xffffff802603ac66 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[6D99A3BE-D531-3780-880B-13F2FC894A4A]@0xffffff7fa6bbf000->0xffffff7fa6bf9fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[766FC23F-452C-3B74-951C-598BB17BCF06]@0xffffff7fa6724000
         com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl(3.7.21)[32B7E2DE-1F9D-3555-B687-7A76A62B81D2]@0xffffff7fa8c41000->0xffffff7fa8c54fff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl(3.7.21)[62689710-EEA7-307A-AC83-B8F25DA88A6A]@0xffffff7fa8c39000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[70E2B65E-A91A-3522-A1A0-79FD63EABB4C]@0xffffff7fa7545000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[766FC23F-452C-3B74-951C-598BB17BCF06]@0xffffff7fa6724000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[6D99A3BE-D531-3780-880B-13F2FC894A4A]@0xffffff7fa6bbf000
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert(1.1.0)[0183904C-6A16-32C4-9405-EEFD7F820B02]@0xffffff7fa8c3c000
         com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAResman(10.0)[53CC0E05-7382-336C-8239-AE884D6CA71A]@0xffffff7fa6c1c000->0xffffff7fa6e91fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[766FC23F-452C-3B74-951C-598BB17BCF06]@0xffffff7fa6724000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.4.1)[F4738C55-B507-3627-A9CA-3D29A5230A03]@0xffffff7fa6c06000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[6D99A3BE-D531-3780-880B-13F2FC894A4A]@0xffffff7fa6bbf000
            dependency: com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl(3.7.21)[4700601D-3FEB-3B86-B2BA-8D71AF84D1C4]@0xffffff7fa6c16000
         com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAGK100Hal(10.0)[DC43029D-568A-3B7C-976B-E922C17F5143]@0xffffff7fa6e9d000->0xffffff7fa704afff
            dependency: com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAResman(10.0.0)[53CC0E05-7382-336C-8239-AE884D6CA71A]@0xffffff7fa6c1c000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[766FC23F-452C-3B74-951C-598BB17BCF06]@0xffffff7fa6724000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: WindowServer

Mac OS version:
14A389

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 14.0.0: Fri Sep 19 00:26:44 PDT 2014; root:xnu-2782.1.97~2/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 89E10306-BC78-3A3B-955C-7C4922577E61
Kernel slide:     0x0000000025c00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8025e00000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8025d00000
System model name: MacBookPro10,1 (Mac-C3EC7CD22292981F)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 6360947082
last loaded kext at 6247471198: com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0 (addr 0xffffff7fa84e3000, size 45056)
loaded kexts:
com.Cycling74.driver.Soundflower    1.6.6
com.movavi.driver.SoundGrabber  1.6.5
com.squirrels.airparrot.framebuffer 3
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.3.0f10
com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler   2.1.0d1
com.apple.driver.AGPM   100.14.37
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    124
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   266.5
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAHardwareConfigDriver   266.5
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   266.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.1
com.apple.GeForce   10.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD4000Graphics   10.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothUSBDFU   4.3.0f10
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.4.12
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.7.3
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.7.21
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferCapri 10.0.0
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.3.0f10
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.10
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHWAccess  1
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.nvidia.NVDAStartup    10.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 2.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyEventDriver   240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 240.2
com.apple.driver.CoreStorageFsck    471
com.apple.driver.AppleFileSystemDriver  3.0.1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 35
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.6.5
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331   800.20.24
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    705.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC  1.6.5
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    10.1.2b3
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360   900.19.8
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.0.7
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   705.4.14
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBXHCI   705.4.14
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 218.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   161
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   218.0.0
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 266.5
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.15
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   200.6
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAGK100Hal    10.0.0
com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAResman  10.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   97
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.7.21
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    156.4
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.7.21
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.3.0f10
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.13d1
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 266.5
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 266.5
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.3.0f10
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.12d1
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.8.0d49
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 705.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltEDMSink    4.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPOutAdapter   4.0.6
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.7.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 245.2
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  705.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   705.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  705.4.9
com.apple.driver.CoreStorage    471
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    4.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    4.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    3.1.7
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 4.2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.3b3
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   700.52
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.7.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 705.4.14
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 389.1
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  3.1
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
Model: MacBookPro10,1, BootROM MBP101.00EE.B05, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.4 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 2.3f36
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 4000, Intel HD Graphics 4000, Built-In
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M, NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M, PCIe, 1024 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54333531533642465238432D50422020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54333531533642465238432D50422020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xEF), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.15.124.12.8)
Bluetooth: Version 4.3.0f10 14890, 3 services, 19 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SM256E, 251 GB
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 23.4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading from your MacBook model (MacBookPro10,1) it seems you either have a mid 2012 or early 2013 Retina MacBook Pro.

`GPU Panic` obviously indicates that the system panics because of the GPU.
Deducting from this, it is possible that your computer is eligible for the GPU replacement program that Apple recently initiated.
[Verify your model here](https://www.apple.com/support/macbookpro-videoissues/) and see if you are eligible. The problem is most likely this then, I had the same issue with my Early 2011 MacBook Pro and a friend in college got the same problem with his Retina MacBook Pro Mid-2012

Comment: @faiz no problem. If this anwsered your question be sure to mark it as answered so other with a similar problem may find it easier.